# My MacBook keeps crashing

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

My Mac keeps crashing with the same error:

> a freed zone element has been modified in zone kalloc.64

Here are four [crash reports](https://gist.github.com/Thermatix/93273d5fe44142d1ca04a10de5d956af) I collected over a period of time.

It happens no matter what I'm doing, using the terminal, the browser, even when the screensaver is on.

I did try disabling avira real time scan (didn't exit) but that didn't stop the crashing.

This is driving me nuts, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say from the crash reports, the good news is that the issue *may* be related to software - a misbehaving third party kernel module may cause a kernel panic.

From you crash reports I see the following 3rd party module:

```
com.avira.kext.FileAccessControl
```

Try updating or removing avira, and see if that helps.

Comment: From what I'd read online i came to a similar conclusion (About it being 3rd party), hence disabling avira's active scan, I'll try an update and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, so, my mac hasn't crashed once since I uninstalled avira, I just wish that it didn't as I kind of don't like leaving my mac unprotected.